# Firebase Dynamic Links created dynamically don't work Android

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I recently manually created a dynamic link from Firebase Console. When clicking short\long links from Firebase console, from an Android device, the links work just fine.

I'm facing 2 problems. When I'm creating a dynamic link by REST API [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links):

1. Short link not saved in console.
2. Android app not opening link no matter how I configure my URL scheme in manifest.

My steps to create dynamic links by REST:

```
POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=MY_API_KEY
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "longDynamicLink": "https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/?link=http://www.socialTanya.co.il/group/groupId&apn=com.ssa.socialtanya&ibi=com.ssa.socialtanya"
}
```

Response:

```
{
"shortLink": "https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/J4qcykV9ol7X3Rh33",
"previewLink": "https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/?link=http://www.socialTanya.co.il/group/itzhar&apn=com.ssa.socialtanya&ibi=com.ssa.socialtanya&d=1"
}
```

When clicking on `https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/J4qcykV9ol7X3Rh33`, I see loading dialog for a few seconds and then the browser opens with "page not found" error.

manifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

       <data
           android:host="www.socialTanya.co.il"
           android:pathPrefix="/group/"
           android:scheme="http"/>

       <data
           android:host="www.socialTanya.co.il"
           android:pathPrefix="/group/"
           android:scheme="https"/>

</intent-filter>
```

Working links from console:

1. `https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/qL6j`
2. `https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/?link=http://www.socialTanya.co.il/group&apn=com.ssa.socialtanya&sd=%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A3+%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93+%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90+%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A3`

Answer (score 2):

OK, after a while, I find the problem and it was totally JAVA issue:

when I send dynamic link from android, I chain some text with `String.format()`:

```
String shareLink = String.format("%s - %s\n%s","to join group","GROUP_NAME","https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/J4qcykV9ol7X3Rh33");
```

I got broken link because upper dash character:

[image]

[image]

and when I click link from mobile I notice the base url changed to:

```
https://r8prz.app-alt.goo.gl
```

**app-alt**
[image]
my geuss is when the dynamic link id is not exist, base url become **app-alt**.

so my solution was, to chain the share link with custom string 'Handmade':

```
String shareLink = "to join group" + "GROUP_NAME" + "https://r8prz.app.goo.gl/J4qcykV9ol7X3Rh33";
```

Comment: I am facing same issue, but not getting how to change deep-link actual url?

Comment: try to describe exactly which url

Comment: seems u build this URL from the console, and not from REST. works for me in Desktop & Android device

Comment: Yes created from console not using rest, So do we have to create using rest only? cant we create using console? it is not opening app even its installed. I have added custom parameters in deep link. without parameters work correct